# How do I get Apiary model details from the rendered documentation?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

I have an API contract defined in Apiary and I'm using the [Resource model](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/examples/8.%20Resource%20Model.md) syntax to enable reuse of payloads.

The documentation rendered by Apiary only shows the model name though (eg Response 200 returns a [Foo][]) - without any further details on what Foo is, or any link to view the attributes in the Foo model.

Given a model, how do I see what its attributes are in the rendered documentation?

*update*
The relevant part of the contract is below:

```
### Manipulating a specific Organisation [/organisations/{id}]
Operations to retrieve and update a specific Organisation.

+ Parameters

    + id (required, guid, `F339ADA5-E836-40FE-8E90-BEF06892762E`) ... The guid Organisation `id`.

+ Model (application/json)

    + Headers

            Link : <http://foobar.com/organisations/F339ADA5-E836-40FE-8E90-BEF06892762E>;rel="self"

    + Body

            {
                "id" : "F339ADA5-E836-40FE-8E90-BEF06892762E",
                "name" : "joe's gardening supplies"
            }

### Retrieve an Organisation [GET]

+ Response 200

        [Organisation][]

### Update an Organisation [PATCH]

+ Request

        [Organisation][]

+ Response 204
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you provide an example, it's just guessing, but my first guess would be **wrong level of indentation**. How example blueprint could look like:

```
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: http://www.google.com

# Model Example
Notes API is a *short texts saving* service similar to its physical paper presence on your table.

# Group Notes
Notes related resources of the **Notes API**

## Note [/notes/{id}]
A single Note object with all its details

+ Parameters
    + id (required, number, `1`) ... Numeric `id` of the Note to perform action with. Has example value.

+ Model

    + Header

            X-My-Header: The Value

    + Body

            { "id": 2, "title": "Pick-up posters from post-office" }

### Retrieve a Note [GET]
+ Response 200 (application/json)

    [Note][]

### Remove a Note [DELETE]
+ Response 204
```

Code above results in [this documentation](http://docs.modelexample.apiary.io/), where model is correctly incorporated on places where it's referenced (and where such reference is supported - i.e. definition of payload).

Sometimes it's helpful to read the [raw version of Apiary's docs on GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/master/examples/8.%20Resource%20Model.md), because it's easier to spot the right, exact format that way.

Comment: cheers - i've updated the question with my example.  it looks very similar to your example so I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

ok, from comparing the two examples I've worked it out.

in my contract the model reference

```
[Organisation][]
```

was indented two tabs instead of one.  :S

that's a really easy mistake to make - would be helpful if Apiary flagged the incorrect indentation level for a model reference.

Comment: Yes this is planned https://github.com/apiaryio/snowcrash/issues/38, sorry about this. Technical detail: two tabs are making it a code block – an opaque asset – parser threats it as a message-payload body